# Putting tick values on top and bottom of matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

My current code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

s = 5
x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
xg = np.exp(-(x**2)/(s**2))
yg = np.exp(-(y**2)/(s**2))

vals = np.meshgrid(xg,yg)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cax = ax.imshow(vals[0]*vals[1])
ax.axis("off")
fig.colorbar(cax,ticks=[0.0,1.0],label="Values (0-1)")
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

I would like the tick values to be on top and bottom of the colorbar (and not on the sides) as in here:

[image]

At the moment, I have done this using Illustrator but I am planning to generate a lot of images like this (for a video) and would like to make these plots automatic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want them nicely centered on the colorbar, then you can't use the yticklabels to achieve this. But you can add the two text fields manually like this:

```
cb = plt.colorbar(im, ticks=[], label="Values (0-1)")
cb.ax.text(0.5, -0.01, '0', transform=cb.ax.transAxes, 
    va='top', ha='center')
cb.ax.text(0.5, 1.0, '1', transform=cb.ax.transAxes, 
    va='bottom', ha='center')
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: That does exactly what I was after. Thanks a lot!